# Is there an event or hook for WCF that happens *after* OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal is set?

Tags: wcf, security, hook

I'm looking for a hook, event, or some other extensibility point that I can use to run a bit of custom code after `OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal` has been set, but before the actual method is called. I've tried using the following:

- `IDispatchMessageInspector` (`AfterReceiveRequest` method)
- `IParameterInspector` (`BeforeCall` method)
- `IAuthorizationPolicy` (`Evaluate` method)
- `ICallContextInitializer` (`BeforeInvoke` method)

At none of these points does `OperationContext.Current.ClaimsPrincipal` have a value.

How do I run a bit of code (in my case, it is authorization and auditing code, based on the incoming claims) after the incoming claims have been set, but before the method itself runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For authorization code at the RP (your application), implement a ClaimsAuthorizationManager to do your authorization checks.  Specifically, override the CheckAccess method and return true/false based on your authorization check.  The ClaimsPrincipal will be accessible from the context that is passed into your CheckAccess method.

More background and a sample are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager.aspx

Comment: Perfect, that works wonderfully (and even seems to be the intended place for this kind of thing)!